# ASP.NET Core Web Api Middleware Custom Exception

Tags: exception, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

***ASP.NET Core Web Api Middleware Converts Custom Exception into Base Exception***

I have created a custom exception class and use it throw an exception. The middleware catches it but throws base exception instead of custom exception. I am not able to understand why it does not catch custom exception.

***Custom Exception***

```cs
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public int HttpStatusCode { get; private set; }

    public CustomException()
    {

    }

    public CustomException(int httpStatusCode, string message):base(message)
    {
        HttpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }
}
```

***Middleware***

```cs
public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    public readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch(CustomException ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        int statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        if (ex is CustomException)
        {
            CustomException se = ex as CustomException;
            statusCode = se.HttpStatusCode;
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new InternalServerErrorResponse(ex.Message)));
    }
}
```

***Exception thrown***

```cs
throw new CustomException(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity, "User is already registered!");
```

When exception is thrown, middleware does not catch custom exception but base Exception. It always goes to the below code block

```cs
catch(Exception ex)
{
     await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: have you changed your `startup` class to use this `middleware`?

Comment: 2 questions: a) is this exception defined in the same project / thrown in the same project b) did you validate if it gets to the part of throwing the exception?

Comment: A) The custom exception class is defined in another project and the main project contains a reference of it. B) did not understand your second question

Comment: Can't reproduce , that works after adding `app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ExceptionMiddleware));` before`app.UseMvc();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use exception filter to handle exceptions and easily manipulate response.

```
public class ExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{


    public ExceptionFilter(IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<JsonExceptionFilter> logger)
    {
        _env = env;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var error = new ApiResponse();
        var exceptionName = context.Exception.GetType().Name;
        var message = context.Exception.Message;

        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            error.Message = context.Exception.Message;
            error.Detail = context.Exception.StackTrace;  
        }
        else
        {
           //Prevent To Show Exception Messages On Production
            error.Message = "Server Error Occured";
            error.Detail = "Something wrong happened";  
        }

        context.Result = new ObjectResult(error)
        {
            //Manipulate Status Code
            StatusCode = 500
        };
    }

}
```

And register to Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            //Catch the exceptions
            options.Filters.Add<ExceptionFilter>();
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

 }
```

Comment: Same issue Yigit. Whether I use a middleware or an exception filter, context.Exception is always System.Exception instead of CustomException. I can see the error message set by CustomException. The CustomException class has some properties that I am not able to access in the filter or middleware because of base exception class. I am using Asp.Net Core 2.2

Answer (score -1):

you have to tell your app to use this `middleware` in `configure` method in your `startup` class like this -

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerManager logger){
    app.ExceptionMiddleware();
}
```

Comment: This code is already there. If it were there in the Configure method then the middleware would not have caught the exception.